# What is the difference of window and timewindow in Flink

Tags: flink-streaming

From Flink documentation I see there are two different window objects:
`timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))` and also `window(TumblingWindow/SlidingWindow) ....`,
I am confused about the difference between them, especially the `timeWindow`, is it a `SlidingWindow` or `TumblingWindow`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JavaDoc for [timeWindow(Time)](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/datastream/KeyedStream.html#timeWindow-org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time-) explicitly says that it's a shortcut for `.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(size))` or `.window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(size))`, depending on the time characteristic of the stream. So yes, it's a TumblingWindow.